# How to add unobtrusive validation for html template fields whats not in the model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

i got a template created for custom zip code field.

My template code is below:

```
@{
    string model = Model ?? string.Empty;
    string zipFirst = "";
    string zipSecond = "";
    if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(model) && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model))
    {
        var values = model.Split('-');
        if(values.Count() == 2)
        {
            zipFirst = values[0] ?? string.Empty;
            zipSecond = values[1] ?? string.Empty;
        }
    }
    var pName = ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName;
    var zipAreaId = "#" + pName + "zipcodearea";
}
<div id="@(pName)zipcodearea">
    <input type="text" maxlength="5" id="zipcodefirst" name="@(pName)codefirst" value="@(zipFirst)" style="width:136px"/> -
    <input type="text" maxlength="4" id="zipcodesecond" name="@(pName)codesecond" value="@(zipSecond)" style="width:120px"/>
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m, new { @class = "generatedZipField"})
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function ($) {
        $('@(zipAreaId) #zipcodefirst').autotab({ target: '@(pName)codesecond', format: 'numeric' });
        $('@(zipAreaId) #zipcodesecond').autotab({ previous: '@(pName)codefirst', format: 'numeric' });
        $('@(zipAreaId)').zipcode();
    });
</script>
```

And i use it like this:

```
[UIHint("ZipCode")]
[Display(Name = "Zip Code")]
public string Zip { get; set; }
```

Like you see in my template i got two fields whats not included in the model.

It is #zipcodefirst and #zipcodesecond.

What i need to achieve is to have two separate fields for full us zip code.

When user fill both fields im using jquery widget for merging them into one string and inserting it into hidden field in template. after form submited value in hidden field getting sent into server.

Whats the problem?

I need to add mvc unobtrusive validation for them two fields whats not in the  model #zipcodefirst and #zipcodesecond.

validation rules

- zipcodefirst field must be filled in first
- then zipcodefirst field is filled you can fill second field
- second field must have 4 digits in it
- first field must have five digits
- cant fill second field while first one is empty or incorectly filled

Im strugling with validation part for quite a while now.... :(
How i could achieve that thru mvc3 unobtrusive validation tools?

any help will be highly apreciated guys.

Answer (score 2):

Add unobrusive data data validation on the textbox by adding `data-val="true"` and use a regular expression for your zip code.

```
<input type="text" data-val="true" data-val-regex="Invalid zip code format" data-val-regex-pattern="YOUR REGEXP HERE" />
```

UPDATE

If you also want it to be required you can add the `data-val-required` attribute.

```
<input type="text" data-val="true" data-val-requred="Zip code is required" data-val-regex="Invalid zip code format" data-val-regex-pattern="YOUR REGEXP HERE" />
```

More information about validation in MVC 3:

http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/mvc3-unobtrusive-validation.html

Comment: thanks indeed!! what about the situation when zip code is required in the model and both fields must be highlighted if they are empty? thanks

Comment: For required fields, add data-val-required="The zip field is required"

Comment: it must be universal component. required setting must be in model and apply dynamically. :(

Comment: It's per definition hard to add validation in the model if it's for inputs that are not present there.